# How to get sed to output all occurances of a group in a string

Tags: regex, sed

So, I have a string like this:

```
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 78471. Job error is: JBO-26067: Failed to add JDBC connection to the connection pool, connection pool is full..
```

And, I want to extract 3 things from it and pipe `|` delimit it using `sed`.
But, the caveat is that, capture groups `\2` and `\3` are optional, and when they don't appear in the input string, I need then to output as empty from sed. So, I declare as optional, but then I never get `\2` or `\3`

my current sed expression:

```
sed -E  -n 's/.*request ([0-9]+).* (ESS-[0-9]+).* (JBO-[0-9]+).*/\1|\2|\3/p'
```

with output of `78471|ESS-07033|JBO-26067`

With optional groups:

```
sed -E  -n 's/.*request ([0-9]+).* (ESS-[0-9]+)?.* (JBO-[0-9]+)?.*/\1|\2|\3/p'
```

Which gives output of `78471||` on the same input:

So, I need:

```
echo 'Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 78471. Job error is: JBO-26067:' | sed ...
```

to produce all 3 values and

```
echo 'Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 blah blah' | sed ...
```

to produce
`78471|ESS-07033|`

and

```
echo 'Execution error for request 78471. Reason: null' | sed ...
```

to produce:
`78471||`

I don't know if I am missing something with sed, or my regex. Ideally I could even reduce my regex

Comment: The problem is that when you make the groups optional, the `.*` before them will be greedy and match past them, so the optional groups don't match anything. You need a non-greedy quantifier, but sed's regexp engine doesn't have this.

Comment: Your best solution will be to use a programming language whose regexp has non-greedy quantifiers.

Answer (score 2):

In Perl, you can't capture an optional group. But you can use a non-capturing optional group `(?:...)?` that contains a capture group.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
strings=(
    'Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 78471. Job error is: JBO-26067:'
    'Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 blah blah'
    'Execution error for request 78471. Reason: null'
)

for s in "${strings[@]}" ; do
    perl -lne '($req, $rea, $job) = /request\ ([0-9]+)
                                    (?:.*
                                        (ESS-[0-9]+)
                                    )?
                                    (?:.*
                                        (JBO-[0-9]+)
                                    )?
                                    /x;
               print "$req|$rea|$job"' <<< "$s"
done
```

I used the `/x` modifier which makes it possible to format the regular expression more readably (it ignores non-quoted whitespace).

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed -E 's/.* request ([0-9]+).*Reason: *(ESS-[0-9]+)?.* (JBO-[0-9]+)?.*/\1|\2|\3/g' file
78471|ESS-07033|JBO-26067
78471|ESS-07033|
78471||

$ cat file
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 78471. Job error is: JBO-26067:
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 blah blah
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: null
```

Comment: On a large set of data, this seems to miss quite a bit

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you want, using any awk:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="|" }
{
    req = ( match($0,/request /) ? substr($0,RSTART+RLENGTH) + 0 : "" )
    ess = ( match($0,/ESS-[0-9]+/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "" )
    jbo = ( match($0,/JBO-[0-9]+/) ? substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH) : "" )
    print req, ess, jbo
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
78471|ESS-07033|JBO-26067
78471|ESS-07033|
78471||
```

and borrowing the sample input [@Choroba](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1030675/choroba) created:

```
$ cat file
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 Job logic indicated a system error occurred while executing an asynchronous java job for request 78471. Job error is: JBO-26067:
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: ESS-07033 blah blah
Execution error for request 78471. Reason: null
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, what I ended up doing was basically realizing that there are only 3 conditions, and coding for each:

patterns.sed

```
s/^[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2} [0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}\|//g
s/["]*Execution error for request //g
s/^([0-9]+)..*(ESS-[0-9]+).*(JBO-[0-9]+).*\|([0-9]+)$/\4|\1|\2|\3/p
s/^([0-9]+)..*(ESS-[0-9]+).*\|([0-9]+)$/\3|\1|\2|/p
s/^([0-9]+)..*\|([0-9]+)$/\2|\1|/p
```

`sed -E -n -f patterns.sed datafile.txt`

This produces:

```
112049845|1011003|ESS-07033|JBO-26067
112297477|5811217||
111982643|1582787|ESS-07033|
```